# How to search list property of class type

Tags: c#, list, find

I have class called capital which contains 2 variables country and capital.Here how it looks...

```
public class country
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Capital { get; set; }
}
```

i have a list of above class type i.e. `List<country>` I can add values using country class variable. Now how to find a particular value for e.g list contains these values

```
country:USA,
capital:New York    

country:China,
capital:Bejing
```

how to find china in above list ...
What will be the best way to do this ?

Comment: NY is a capital of USA? You've killed my geography skills. :)

Comment: glad someone noticed it...lol :)

Comment: since we're noticing things here, Bejing killed my spelling skills too. :P lol

Comment: i stopped using google lol...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [.Find()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc.aspx). Using Linq Extension methods will require you to reference System.Linq. This is great if you're on .NET 3.5 and above. Else, just use Find.

```
namespace _16828321
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Country> c = new List<Country>()
            {
                new Country(){ Capital = "New York", CountryName = "USA"},
                new Country(){ Capital = "Beijing", CountryName = "China"}
            };

            Country result = c.Find(country => country.CountryName == "China");
        }
    }

    public class Country
    {
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
        public string Capital { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is using Linq:

```
var countries = new List<country>();

countries.Add(new country { Country = "USA", Capital = "Washington" });

countries.Add(new country { Country = "China", Capital = "Bejing" });

var usaFromCountries = countries.FirstOrDefault( c => c.Country == "USA" );

if(usaFromCountries == null)
{
   Console.WriteLine("USA did not exist in countries list");
}
else
{
    Console.Write("Capital of the USA is ");
    Console.WriteLine(usaFromCountries.Capital);
}
```

Comment: OMG. Why `Where` with condition, and then `FirstOrDefault` without it? `countries.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Country == "USA")`

Comment: Linq is surely easiest but is it ideal way to do it or using Find method of list i.e List.Find(s => s.country == "USA")

Comment: Use Find. It doesn't need System.Linq reference which is ideal if you're using older .NET versions (like 2.0).

Comment: If for some reason you are bound to Framework 2.0, use Find(). If not, you will have Linq in your project anyway and Linq works on any IEnumerable, not just Lists. In the end, both methods do exactly the same, use the one you like best.

Comment: @SDKLive `List.Find` and `Enumerable.FirstOrDefault` are both perfectly easy to use.  The only reasons why you'd use `Find` over `FirstOrDefault` are preference and microscopic (basically meaningless) optimizations.  The microscopic optimization with `Find` over `FirstOrDefault` is that `FirstOrDefault` uses an iterator under the hood while `Find` uses a regular for loop.  Creating the iterator can take a probably negligible amount of time.